# Refrescar consulta PHP con load() de jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Intento refrescar una consulta a la base de datos en mi pagina web con el siguiente script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sqltable').load("index.php #sqltable");
    },5000);
</script>
```

`index.php` es el nombre del documento donde se encuentra todo el código

`sqltable` es el id del tag donde se muestra la información de la BD

La parte en la que intento refrescar el contenido:

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
    $result = mysql_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($datos = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr id="sqltable">
        <td id="sqltable"><?php echo $datos['ID'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

En el navegador he observado el siguiente error:

```
uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined
```

Sobre la segunda línea del ejemplo que indico mas arriba.

El problema es que no se actualiza el contenido, ni en los 5 segundos ni nunca. ¿Dónde puede estar el problema?

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que la etiqueta y lenguaje correcto para tu pregunta es [**javascript**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) y no **java**, son dos lenguajes muy distintos, por favor corrije esto y además agrega también la etiqueta **jquery**

Comment: ¿Por qué le pasas ` #sqltable` a la llamada en la cargas el php? Además, estás reutilizando ese identificador en más de un elemento, cosa que te puede causar problemas.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error en la consola del navegador? por cierto desconozco que el método `ready()` de **jQuery** acepte un segundo parámetro para especificar retraso, creo que es erróneo eso colega

Comment: @JaviMollá tiene razón, puede que sea la causa del problema, al llamar ese método sobre ese elemento `$('#sqltable').load(...` no es necesario que le pases ese segundo parámetro

Comment: @Josbert Ahora que lo he mirado si, referente al $(document): '$ is not defined'

Comment: ¿Como estas cargando [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)? desde un **CDN** `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-...`?

Comment: @JaviMollá , he probado a quitar el segundo parámetro #sqltable y no funciona. Lo he puesto tanto en la tabla como en el TD, pero no se concretamente donde ponerlo.

Comment: @Josbert concretamente desde `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-lastest.js`></script>

Comment: No existe ese archivo, lo puedes comprobar colocado era **url** en tu navegador y te dará `404`, cámbialo por este `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`

Comment: Además te recomiendo no usar la extensión **mysql** de *PHP* ya que esta obsoleta, en cambio usa la nueva versión [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

Estas recargando una pagina asi misma.
Desde el `index.php` intentas cargar la pagina `index.php`

Intenta crear otra pagina que solo carga el resultado de tu consulta MySQL en invocala  `$('#sqltable').load("otrapagina.php");`